# Correlated sub-query causing this error - LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When writing correlated sub-queries in BigQuery using a WHERE clause, it is  resulting in an Error.
LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

However it works in other SQL engines, I am not understanding the error or how to rewrite the queries.

Different queries of the same type causing the same error.

```
SELECT
  out.*
FROM
  `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students` AS out
WHERE
  2 >= (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students` AS t1
  WHERE
    out.age < t1.age)
```

reporting students who are older than at most two other students.

Comment: Don't know bigquery (so not sure if it deviates from standard SQL). Just to say logically I think you need to change "out.age < t1".age to "out.age > t1.age" if you want students older than at most 2 others. Doesn't explain your error though.

Comment: Is the age field an integer, decimal?

Comment: i advice you look into [window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions)

Comment: a general rewrite  `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ..., ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY age) AS row_number) AS alias WHERE alias.row_number >= 2` which is believe should give the same results as your co-related subquery because you simulate or emulate a rank or row_number with you co-related subquery.

Comment: Otherwise see and read *"However it works in other SQL engines, I am not understanding the error or how to rewrite the queries."* see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results

Comment: DRapp - integer, retrieving the students who are older than zero, one or two other students.

Comment: it is important to carefully pick tags for your question to avoid massive not relevant comments and answers!!! next time if your question is very specific to BigQuery - I would recommend using ONLY bigquery tag and not include sql tag. Obviously you own the question and it is up to you :o)

Comment: *"it is important to carefully pick tags for your question to avoid massive not relevant comments and answers"* @MikhailBerlyant yea it indeed seams Google BigQuery side steps on some parts far away from standard ANSI/ISO SQL standards..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(ORDER BY age RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) cnt
  FROM `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students` 
)
WHERE cnt BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Another, less effective and thus not recommended but still an option is to use CROSS JOIN to mimic non-equality LEFT JOIN

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(out).*
FROM `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students` AS out
CROSS JOIN `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students` AS t1
WHERE out.age > t1.age 
GROUP BY out.id
HAVING COUNT(t1.age) <= 2
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, Those answers were great.

Comment: sure: glad it worked for you. also, please read my comment below your question. my recommendation is first to use only bigquery task and only if this will not bring helpful answer  - then add sql tag. just recommendation

Comment: SQL 2003+ standard Window function to the rescue +1 this is how you should rank and not simulate/emulate it with SQL 92 standards co-related subquery and COUNT(*)., `ANY_VALUE()` that is like playing russian roulette with your resultset which i don't recommend to use.. @TheoHayes

Answer (score 0):

Horrible thing you are trying to do, but lets think about what you DO have.  For every "OUT" record, you are requerying every assignment again to get the count.  What I would suggest is a 3-level query.  The inner-most is to get all distinct "age" values (hoping integer based).  Then get the counts LESS than to create a pre-aggregate result.  Then you can join to the original out based on the outer-most OUT value vs repeated querying.  Something like

```
select
      out
   from
      `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students` AS out
         JOIN ( select
                      UniqAge.Age,
                      ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                           FROM `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students`
                           WHERE age < UniqAge.age) CountUnderAge
                   from
                      ( select distinct age
                           from `august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students` ) UniqAge
              ) PQByAge
        on out.age = PQByAge
        AND PQByAge.CountUnderAge <= 2
```

This query is based on the Age column being INTEGER based (non decimal).

Comment: *"When writing correlated sub-queries in BigQuery using a WHERE clause, it is resulting in an Error."* ... why would `select
                      UniqAge.Age,
                      ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                           FROM august-monolith-205810.Assignment.students
                           WHERE age < UniqAge.age)` co-relation subquery in your query work and why did the topicstarters co-relation subquery fail? I very doubt this query will solve it

Comment: @RaymondNijland, lets say you have 100k rows, but only 75 distinct ages.  The inner query will run once to get the counts for all unique ages once.  THEN join to the outer 100k vs running the count less than age 100k times per outer row.

Comment: i know what a co-related subquery is or how your subquery executes you dont have to explain.. did you read the topicstarters message what was mine point.. *""When writing **correlated sub-queries** in BigQuery using a WHERE clause, it is resulting in an **Error.**""* you are also wrote a co-related subquery so i very much doubt your query would work better..