# Why does BigQuery complain about a left join error when I introduce a subquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

## Question

Is there an explanation for *why* the below unhelpful error message displays the way that it does, or is there an otherwise documented best practice for leveraging potentially-missing data in subqueries?

## Issue

BigQuery yields a confusing and unhelpful error when I reference a field from a table that is left-joined into a CTE.

### Error message

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.
```

### Particular goal

My *particular* case is an attempt to calculate business days between two dates by leveraging a subquery against an existing `dates` table.

### Reproducible example

The below query throws the following error when I introduce the subquery as a `select`ed field.

It appears that the reference to `d2` causes the query to break.

```sql
with

first_dates as (
  select 1 as id, cast('2020-01-01' as date) as d
  union all
  select 2 as id, cast('2020-02-01' as date) as d
),

second_dates as (
  select 1 as id, cast('2020-01-02' as date) as d
),


timelines as (
  select 
    first_dates.id,
    first_dates.d as d1,
    second_dates.d as d2
  from
    first_dates
    -- This is the only left join in my query, and looks fine to me!
    left join second_dates using (id)
)

select 
  *,
  (
    select count(*)
    from <my_example_dates_table>
    where 
      date >= d1 
      and date < d2
      and is_business_day
      ) as n_business_days
from 
  timelines
```

#### Hypothesis

My current hypothesis is that BigQuery's backend is converting the subquery into a left join and encountering an error when it attempts to do so. If so, I believe the error message should be improved.

#### Research so far

I've found many SO links referencing this same issue, but **I haven't found any answers that explain why exactly this error arises, why the error message is so unhelpful, and whether there is a best practice for recreating what seems like a reasonable query pattern in BigQuery**.

Therefore, I implore the person who will inevitably want to close this as a duplicate to leave it open, since it's specifically asking for an answer as to *why the error message is displayed like it is*.

Many are answered already suggesting specific alternative approaches to particular problems:

- [LEFT OUTER JOIN Error creating a subquery on bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136871/left-outer-join-error-creating-a-subquery-on-bigquery)
- [Correlated sub-query causing this error - LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972351/correlated-sub-query-causing-this-error-left-outer-join-cannot-be-used-without)
- [LEFT JOIN with an OR in the ON clause BigQuery Standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444613/left-join-with-an-or-in-the-on-clause-bigquery-standard-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides @rtenha comment. This is a known issue with Bigquery and can be tracked in [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152193691)

Also, in these situation is suggested to change **<=** or **>=** to **=**.

Additionally, taking this query as example:

> SELECT
>       *,
>       (
>       SELECT
>         MIN(chosen)
>       FROM
>         chosen_t
>       WHERE
>         chosen >= requested) AS rounded_v   FROM
>       tots)

A workaround suggested by the BigQuery Team, is adding fake equality join predicate as this:

> SELECT
>       *,
>       (
>       SELECT
>         MIN(chosen)
>       FROM
>         chosen_t
>       WHERE
>         chosen >= requested and 0 * chosen = 0 * requested) AS rounded_v

Answer (score 2):

First, consider this query (simplified from your query):

```
with

first_dates as (
  select 1 as id, cast('2020-01-01' as date) as d
  union all
  select 2 as id, cast('2020-02-01' as date) as d
)

select 
  *,
  (
    select count(*)
    from utility.calendar -- just a simple calendar
    where 
      calendar_date = d
      ) as n_business_days
from 
  first_dates
```

This executes, and if you look at the 'Execution Details' in the BQ interface, you can indeed see a join happening. Your hypothesis here seems to be correct.

If you change the subquery to `calendar_date >= d`, then you get the `LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join` error.  Assuming the subquery-to-left-join transformation actually is occurring, then the question becomes 'Why do I need an equality in my left join?'

I do not know the exact reasons, but my hunch is it has something to do with scalability and query cost estimation. If your right-hand-side table is partitioned, an inequality (`>`,`<`,etc) join would not benefit from the partitioning as each row on the left-hand-side would have to compare to the entire right-hand-side.

The solution here is to usually `CROSS JOIN` and then filter. This moves any comparisons from the `join` clause to the `where` clause.

```
select
  id, d1, d2, count(*) as ct
from timelines
cross join <my_example_dates_table>
where date >= d1 
  and date < d2
  and is_business_day
group by 1,2,3
```